# How to get current value of UIPickerView AFTER it has already been selected

Tags: swift, uipickerview, delegation

Call me stupid, but I just cannot figure out how you can get the current value of a UIPickerView *after* it has already been selected. There are plenty of SO Q&As on getting it if it's just been changed by using the delegate's `didSelectRowAt` method, but what if it's already been set a while ago? You can't manually call this delegate method... can you?

I know this is probably an easy one, but your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIPickerView` has a `selectedRow` that will return the currently selected row:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview/1614369-selectedrow

```
let selected = myPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) //gets the selection in the first component of the picker
```

Comment: Oh my gosh how did I not see that. That was my first assumption and when searching for a method such as this I literally just missed it... twice in a row. Thank you. I'll accept it in 11 mins once SO let's me.